# Is there a faster way to make GET requests in Go?

Tags: python, http, go, wget

Consider this program:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

var url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fe/FlumeRide%2C_Liseberg_-_last_steep_POV.ogv"

func main() {
    response, _ := http.Get(url)
    defer response.Body.Close()

    f, _ := os.Create("output.ogv")
    defer f.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(f, response.Body)
}
```

It has the same functionality as `wget $url` and takes ~**7.3 seconds** to run (for me). `wget` takes only ~**4.6 seconds**. Why the huge discrepancy? This trivial Python program, which loads the entire video into memory before writing it to disk, takes around **5.2 seconds**:

```
import requests

url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fe/FlumeRide%2C_Liseberg_-_last_steep_POV.ogv"

def main():
    r = requests.get(url)
    with open('output.ogv','wb') as output:
        output.write(r.content)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

## Profiling

I've investigated this quite a bit. Here are some approaches I've taken:

1. Use different buffer sizes in `io.Copy`
2. Use other Readers/Writers
3. Concurrency / parallelism
4. Downloading larger files

#### Different buffer sizes

I tried many different buffer sizes using `io.CopyBuffer`, and I found that the default buffer size of 32KB leaves me with the best speeds (which are still 1.6 to 1.8 times slower than `wget` and Python's `reqeusts`).

#### Other Readers/Writers

All of the other readers and writers were negligibly slower than using `io.Copy`. I tried using `(f *File) Write` and some other buffered readers/writers.

#### Concurrency / Parallelism

I even wrote a fairly long program that uses `range` in headers to download this file in parallel, but as expected I didn't seem any remarkable improvements in speed.

#### Larger files

I downloaded a file more than three times as large as this one, and my Go implementation is still 1.5 to 2 times slower than wget and requests.

## Other Things of Note

1. I'm building a binary before timing anything.
2. The vast majority of the time is spent on actually writing/copying `response.Body`. The part seems to account for all but ~0.3 seconds of elapsed time, regardless of how large the file I'm downloading is.

---

So what am I doing wrong? Should I just expect GET requests to take this much longer in Go?

Comment: what version of go?

Comment: Are you using `go run` to execute the program?

Comment: @MellowMarmot No, I'm building a binary before timing anything.

Comment: @superfell I'm using go version 1.7 darwin/amd64

Comment: most likely wget use gzip but go does not.

Comment: If the client receives the data in dribs and drabs, this can result in more file io than the Python version.  Try a single write to the file as in the Python versoin: `var b bytes.Buffer; io.Copy(&b, response.Buffer); f.Write(b.Bytes())`.

Comment: @MellowMarmot Still around 7 seconds.... At this point I think it might be something about my Go version, considering this and the answer by PsyWolf

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what to tell you.  I just tried to duplicate your findings, but for me, all 3 versions take roughly the same amount of time

```
wget   8.035s  
go     8.174s
python 8.242s
```

Maybe try the same experiment inside a clean VM or docker container?

Comment: I think you're right. I'm going to try this with Go 1.7 on Arch tonight. I'll report back as to how it goes. Any thoughts on why Go 1.7 amd64/darwin does this?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I ran my tests with Go 1.7 on linux/amd64.  You might want to check out the brand new https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptrace/ package that was introduced in Go 1.7.  I haven't used it myself yet, but it looks like exactly what you'd need to debug this.